# Automatic copying of DLLs in qmake won't work

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to get qmake to automatically copy the DLLs for my program to the target path, but it's not working. This is the relevant part of my .pro-file:

```
QT_DIR = C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin
MY_TARGET_DIR = $$PWD/debug
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/QT5CORED.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/QT5SERIALPORTD.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/QT5WIDGETSD.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/LIBWINPTHREAD-1.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += QT_DIR/LIBSTDC++-6.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += C:/qwt-6.1.0/lib/QWTD.DLL
extra_libs.files = MY_LIB_FILES
extra_libs.path = MY_TARGET_DIR
INSTALLS += extra_libs
```

QMake runs normally, but make install issues a warning

```
 Nothing to be done for 'install'.
```

The DLLs are not copied to the target directory. Also, I tried to write the code more elegantly, but it seems that some QMake variables such as $$QMAKE_LIBDIR are empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is qmake from Qt 5.1.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepend the `QT_DIR` variable with double dollars to make this work:

```
QT_DIR = C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin
MY_TARGET_DIR = $${PWD}/debug
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/QT5CORED.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/QT5SERIALPORTD.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/QT5WIDGETSD.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/LIBWINPTHREAD-1.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += $${QT_DIR}/LIBSTDC++-6.DLL
MY_LIB_FILES += C:/qwt-6.1.0/lib/QWTD.DLL
extra_libs.files = MY_LIB_FILES
extra_libs.path = MY_TARGET_DIR
INSTALLS += extra_libs
```

**Side Note:**
There is [a bug in qmake](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16372) which causes that files containing special characters (like the `+` in the name of `libstdc++-6.dll`) are not copied during install on Windows. Check [my comment in the bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16372?focusedCommentId=201076&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-201076) for a workaround.